# Can a Sql server AlwaysOn group be a transactional replication subscriber?

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication, subscriber, alwayson

If I have a Sql server AlwaysOn Availability Group, can I do a transactional push replication to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can be. Check out [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403414.aspx) under the restrictions of alwayson and replication.

Comment: Did I read it correctly, that the replication is not automatically transfered to the secondary replica when the primary sql server goes down? Additionally, can the publisher/distributor be sql server 2008 r2?

Comment: it will be automatically transferred for push subscription b/c it is taking to your listener defined as linked server.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the sql server version of the publisher?

Comment: The publisher can't be newer than the distributor and subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

you can't configure subscriber using management studio

```
-- commands to execute at the publisher, in the publisher database:  
   use [<publisher database name>]  
   EXEC sp_addsubscription @publication = N'<publication name>',   
   @subscriber = N'<availability group listener name>',   
   @destination_db = N'<subscriber database name>',   
   @subscription_type = N'Push',   
   @sync_type = N'automatic', @article = N'all', @update_mode = N'read        only', @subscriber_type = 0;
```

GO

```
   EXEC sp_addpushsubscription_agent @publication = N'<publication     name>',   
   @subscriber = N'<availability group listener name>',   
   @subscriber_db = N'<subscriber database name>',   
   @job_login = null, @job_password = null, @subscriber_security_mode = 1;
```

GO

```
  and push subscription better for alwayson with replication subscriber.
```